# Substitute partial line in vim using only substitute command

Tags: vim

I am editing a file with lines similar to the following:

```
{"a_function", a_function},
{"a_second_function", a_second_function},
```

I would like to convert the underscores to spaces, but only within the quotes.  Is there a way to do this just by using the `:substitute` command?  I know I can do this by recording a macro and there are probably plugins out there that can do this, but for the sake of cleverness I'd like to do this in one shot with the `:substitute` command.

Comment: Is the text always repeated like that? `{"x", x}, {"y", y}` and so on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim regex for replacing spaces within quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974768/vim-regex-for-replacing-spaces-within-quotes)

Comment: In this particular case the text is repeated in that pattern.  Though, I have other places where it might not be the case.

It looks as though my question may actually be a duplicate of that other question.  I will have to review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command should do what you want:

```
:%s/\v(".{-}")/\=substitute(submatch(1), "_", " ", "g")
```

I capture the first pair of quotes on each line then I use it as replacement with all underscores removed.

Comment: Based on the linked question I went with: `%s/"\zs\(\w*\)\ze"/\=substitute(submatch(1), '_', ' ', 'g')/g`.


The `\=subsitute()` jazz is what I was missing from my vim repertoire.

Comment: Just curious. How is that pattern different from `"[^"]*"`?

Comment: @RSahu, it's just a different way to reach the same goal.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to select the text to be manipulated in visual block mode, then do

`:'<,'>s/\%V_/ /g`, which would only substitute in the visual area.

This is simple and fast, though not so flexible and not always feasible.

---

And yet sometimes a carefully created regex pattern is also a choice.

In your simple example, this would suffice: `s/\v_(\S*")@=/ /g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\(".*\)_\(.*"\)/\1 \2/g
```

Each time you call this, it will replace one underscore in all the document. So if you have a maximum o 5 underscores in between quotations you just call it 5 times and you'll be set.

Comment: Not a bad idea. There are some simpler solutions using submatch in the question I linked you might like.

Answer (score 1):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides a `:SubstituteInSearch` command. With it, you first search for the quoted strings, then perform a `:substitute` only within the matches:

```
/".\{-}"
:SubstituteInSearch/_/ /g
```